# IPhone - Application behaving differently after some time in background

Tags: iphone, background

I would like you to help me here.

I'm developing an app that works in the background. It's a location-based app and I think I'm going crazy because when I'm debugging the app in the device it works perfectly, I make it sleep I wake it up and I works as expected. Then I unplug the device from the computer and I put in my pocket and whenever I open it, it sometimes works and other it doesn't, I'm talking about several hours in the background.

Are there any known issues about this? My device is running iOS 5.0 and I'm developing for iOS 4.0

Thanks

Comment: Does it crash? - Check the device crashlogs in the organizer.

Comment: It doesnt crash, that's the problem, Im reading the console(with another app) and it seems it's doing the right thing but it's like it paralises, it wakes up and only does half of the job.

Answer (score 0):

Applications in the background are handled by iOS. Therefore if iOS "thinks" that it needs memory it maybe frees some of the memory your app needs to run.

Have you tried to look into it with Instruments?

Comment: the thing is that this happens after hours, while Im not debugging so I can't see what's happening with Instruments,